TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
I am developing a server using Spring Boot 3, but for some reason, the test code is not running properly and is throwing an error as mentioned in the title.
I have seen various solutions on the internet since it seems to be a common error, but none of them have worked.
How can I resolve this issue?
I already tried to change Run tests using Gradle -> IntelliJ IDEA, but it also didn't work.
build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}
jar.enabled(true)
bootJar.enabled(true)

dependencies {
    implementation project(':joon-core')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:3.2.4'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.5'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation "org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test:3.0.3"

    // Mockito
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core"

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Test
@SpringBootTest
class AdminApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    @Test
    void given_when_then() {
        adminService.execute("ID", "joon");
    }
}

Error


Remove org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher then run again.
